# Design this Button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, button

How can I design this kind of button in flutter?

[image: How can I design this kind of button in flutter?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, adjust to your needs:

```
Container(
            color:  Color.fromRGBO(133,208,212,1),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                shape: StadiumBorder(),
                color:  Color.fromRGBO(133,208,212,1),
                shadows: <BoxShadow>[
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    spreadRadius: 8,
                    blurRadius: 3,
                    offset: Offset(0, 0),
                  ),
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                    spreadRadius: 3,
                    blurRadius: 3,
                    offset: Offset(5, 2),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Sign in',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

The first Container is there just to highlight it's child, so it's not important

Answer (score 1):

You can use elevated button with transparent color and white border and shadow

Comment: It should be comment, A code will be helpful . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its help to you.

```
Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      height: 80,
      width: 200,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80),
      ),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          //Write your onPressed function here
          print('Button Pressed');
        },
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.teal[100],
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(70),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Sign In',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: I do not want to be rude, but this is not even close to the required outlook.